# Email Tracking for Crm Application

Tags: crm, email, google-apps-marketplace

I'm working on a CRM application and need to track email of clients. How can i implement emal sync functionality ?

I'll initially use it for google apps marketplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to implement this.

You could use a Gmail Contextual Gadget - which inserts a configurable gadget into Gmail.  You can design the gadget to access your CRM.  https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets

You could use the Gmail API to connect Gmail to your CRM.  Build a synchronisation process that checks for a "CRM" label for example in the users inbox.  When labelled the email can be added to the CRM.  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

You could build a Chrome Extension that extends Gmail and allows for CRM access.  The extension can manipulate the Gmail dom.  Example of this is Gmail.js  https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js?utm_source=tuicool

Comment: Thanks.
I'll try Gmail API.

Comment: I'm using Gmail API but having a issue using it. 
I can get mails between 2 dates but unable to get mail between 2 intervals in time (between 2 hours).